# Android BottomNavigation is not highlighting properly with Navigation Controller

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement [Nagivation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) from Android Architecture Components. I am able to navigate successfully across my fragments. I am trying to attach it to my bottom navigation but I am unable to use it properly. I can navigate between fragments successfully with `Navigation.findNavController(View).navigate(R.id.Fragment)` but when I do that by using any UI component or back button, a highlight from my bottom navigation is not changing as shown in the following gif

[image]

My code is as follows for `MainActivity.kt`,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var navController: NavController


    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.addEmotionFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }


}
```

For `HomeFragment.kt`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.addEmotionFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use navigation-ui.

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:' + navigationVersion //currently 1.0.0-alpha05
```

in activity

```
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, navController)
```

And make sure your fragment id match menu id.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:title="Home"/>
```

Comment: I just wanted to add one more information into this answer is that you need to have SAME id of your fragment in your `R.menu.navigation` and in your `R.navigation.my_navigation_file` for Navigation-UI to work ! I spent searching for 3-4 hours on multitude of blogs to finally understand this :)

Comment: @user345280 This works very good, but pressing back goes to the first fragments (not the previously shown fragment) is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually set a checked property inside your button click like:

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.addEmotionFragment)
        .... (Over Here)
    }
```

The Java Code would be:

`MenuItem menuItem = YourBottomViewObject.getMenu().getItem(1);
menuItemsetChecked(true);
MenuItem menuItem = YourBottomViewObject.getMenu().getItem(0);
menuItemsetChecked(false);`

Comment: Had to rewrite this in kotlin but worked like a charm.